# Roller's problem on median groups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, examples, geometric-group-theory

At the end of his dissertation *Poc Sets, Median Algebras and Group Actions*, Martin Roller asks

> A group $G$ is called *median* if it acts freely and transitively on a [median algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_algebra). This is equivalent to saying that the Cayley graph with respect to a certain set of generators is a cubing. [...] Characterize all presentations of median groups.

Do you know any work on the subset? The only examples I am able to imagine are of the form
$$\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n \mid [x_i,x_j]=1 \ \text{and} \ x_k^2=1 \ \text{for some} \ 1 \leq i,j,k \leq n \rangle.$$
Are there other simple examples?

Answer (score 4):

Below are a few examples of groups admitting a median graph as a Cayley graph. (About the terminology "median groups", notice the possible confusion with groups acting geometrically on median spaces.)

- **Right-angled Artin groups.** Given a (simplicial) graph $\Gamma$, define $$A(\Gamma)= \langle \text{vertices of $\Gamma$} \mid [u,v]=1, \ (u,v) \in E(\Gamma) \rangle.$$ Then the Cayley graph of $A(\Gamma)$ with respect to the generating set given by the previous presentation is median graph, or if you prefer, it is naturally the one-skeleton of a CAT(0) cube complex.
- **Right-angled Coxeter groups.** The same comment holds for the group $$\langle \text{vertices of $\Gamma$} \mid u^2=1 \ (\text{$u$ vertex}), \ [u,v]=1 \ (\text{$u,v$ adjacent}) \rangle$$
- **LOG groups.** Given an oriented graph $\Gamma$ whose edges are labelled by its vertices (such that any vertex labels at most one edge), one can define the group $$G(\Gamma)= \langle \text{vertices of $\Gamma$} \mid cac^{-1}=b, \ (a \mid c \mid b) \in E(\Gamma) \rangle$$ where $(a \mid c \mid b) \in E(\Gamma)$ means that there exists an oriented edge from $a$ to $b$ which is labelled by $c$. In his paper *On the realization of Wirtinger presentations as knot groups*, Rosebrock determines precisely when the square complex associated to the above presentation is nonpositively curved.
- **C(4)-T(4) presentations.** For any C(4)-T(4) presentation whose relations have length four, the corresponding two-complex is a nonpositively curved square complex.
- **Right-angled mock reflection groups.** In his paper *Right-angled mock reflection and mock Artin groups*, Scott classifies explicitely all the groups acting vertex-simply-transitively on CAT(0) cube complexes with $\mathbb{Z}_2$ edge-stabilisers.
- **Right-angled mock Artin groups.** In the same way that a right-angled Artin group may be associated to a right-angled Coxeter group, Scott introduced right-angled mock Artin groups from right-angled mock reflection groups.
- **BMW-groups.** In addition to Mark's answer, I would like to mention Caprace's survey *Finite and infinite quotients of discrete and indiscrete groups* (Section 4, *Lattices in products of trees after M. Burger, S. Mozes and D. Wise*).

Answer (score 3):

There are compact nonpositively-curved square complexes $X$ so that $X$ has a single vertex and the universal cover of $X$ is a CAT(0) square complex isomorphic to the product of two trees, but $\pi_1X$ is not of the form you've mentioned, and doesn't even have a finite-index subgroup admitting such a presentation.  For example, there is this [paper of Wise](https://www.ems-ph.org/journals/show_pdf.php?issn=0010-2571&vol=82&iss=4&rank=1).